# why Gwan cache my result, could I disable it?

Tags: c, g-wan

I had a problem about gwan cache, currently I visit a page serve by gwan (write in C) , which will execute some functions during visit, however, when I visit the same page few more time, gwan will directly give me the result without execute the function...

As the function is to update the information about user activity, is there any way to force  gwan to run the functions every time I visit?

Thank you v much!!

Comment: G-WAN's microcaching "feature" helps it deliver the fastest benchmarks against everything else. Had it not had this, it couldn't claim faster speeds than everything else.

Comment: @Mike, that's a lie - and you know it (it suffices to test G-WAN without caching: http://gwan.ch/faq#cache). But your goal is not to inform people, right? Further, **DEDICATED CACHE SERVERS like Varnish** are much slower than G-WAN, proof that caching alone is not the reason behind G-WAN's speed.

Comment: How to do return it in nodejs, because process.exit(2000) doesnot help stop caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use different urls every req. For example:

```
/?activity&secret=mq4s1Xsi&timestamp=19457278
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried before, but it not work if I click the link twice or more at the same page!

Comment: In the "secret" and "timestamp" fields, you MUST use an ever-changing value to have distinct requests. Note that the **RC_NOCACHE** return code has been added recently to stop the continuous stream of duplicate questions and erroneous answers (by new dedicated stackoverflow accounts) on this site.

Comment: @Gil, I can't find RC_NOCACHE in gwan.h .

Comment: As previously said, *"RC_NOCACHE was added recently"*, and this change (like many others) is not yet published. The next release will be a major release.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know English enough. Thanks for your answer!